# How to number pages in pdf document?

Tags: pdf

How can I add numbers to pages in pdf document?

Is there a free software for this?

I found in google only full version of Adobe Acrobat, which can make it.

[This works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXvjpvt9V8s), but I need to add number in right corner for each odd page and in left corner for each even page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Preview. Tools Menu/Annotate/Text, or it's the top right icon next to the search box, then icons appear below for annotation choices.